# Gas station network use cases

Tags: gas, dapps, dapp-development, keymanagement, use-cases

I'm trying to understand the purpose of [EIP 1613](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1613). Related to this [website](https://gsn.openzeppelin.com/) says "No more Metamask".

So it assumes that a user does not have direct access to his private key / wallet. It means the key pair must be genereted by (d)app owner. In this case the (d)app owner has full access to the user account, e.g. for receiving, sending txs.

So why we need at all such complex system with Relays, RelayReciepeints, Hub etc? If the gas payer always is the only one person - the (d)app owner.

Are there some use cases where this approach is really useful and make sense?

Comment: The idea is not that you don't need Metamask but you don't need Ether to use a dapp. For example a relayer may accept fiat or other tokens to forward a transaction for you. The idea is to lower the entry barrier which Metamask is used figuratively.